# How to mute or fix the console warnings in react 16.9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

have upgraded to react 16.9 but seeing these errors in the console:

`Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.`

and

`Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use`

I know the fix should be to put `UNSAFE_` in front, however I am not using these methods anywhere

so I'm guessing one of the packages I'm using is using one of these methods, how do I work out which package it is and fix it?

alternatively is there a way to just suppress it?

Comment: warnings will not show in production mode

Comment: @FlashThunder I'd rather get rid of them in all envs if possible

Comment: The warning must be showing you the name of the package that you need to update at the very last line of it. Please check carefully.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta Not all packages have fixed this. We can also expect some packages which are no longer maintained, to not ever have this fixed. So this question is still valid imo.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same issue. ALthough i am not able to fix it but i definitely know how to mute it in the console. So when you open the console u will see a default levels options next to filter bar under console. Just click on that and unselect warning options. 
And kaboom thats it. You will not see those annoying warning anymore.
Hope this helps!